# Does spark.jdbc.write use connection pooling?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc

I am using spark to push some hive tables to a RDBMS using
     `spark.write.jdbc(...)`

I am seeing lots of open /killed connections on the RDBMS side, pretty much one per task. So my question is-does it use connection pooling? If so, how do I configure one? If not, is the only way to do it all manually using

```
df.rdd.forachPartition { // Open a connection, prepare batch and insert ??? }
```

Comment: Changed to foreach  as suggested

Comment: @user1113782 Were you able to find a solution on how to avoid creating a new connection for each task? (Using connection pool)